# Fedora 35: Suddenly vi screen started looking funny!

Tags: highlight, color

A few days ago, vi started loading files and applying some strange highlighting. I have done nothing (on purpose anyway) to edit colors (don't know how).

Can anyone explain how to fix this? Default colors are fine.

[image]

*edit / update:* Q/A from the comments

I tried the suggested commands on two text files - one that's an XML and one just text

The xml file generates:

```
:setlocal filetype?   filetype=xml
:setlocal syntax?     syntax=xml
:setlocal report?     report=2
:filetype             filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:OFF
:set background       background=light
:colorscheme          default
```

The plain file generates:

```
:setlocal filetype?   filetype=text
:setlocal syntax?     syntax=text
:setlocal report?     report=2
:filetype             filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:OFF
:set background       background=light
:colorscheme          default
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Assuming this vi is actually a build of Vim, what does `:setlocal filetype? syntax?` report? What about `:filetype` ? What about `:set background`, `:colorscheme`?

Comment: my guess: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/10449

Comment: edited Q with commands / responses

Comment: check your terminal configuration. Note, your configuration says `:set background=light` that is just wrong for a dark terminal. Also, what is $TERM set to and what terminal are you actually using? can you try xterm?

Comment: echo $TERM generates: xterm-256color... how do I change "background" to dark (my other system has it set to "dark" and vi works as expected)?

Comment: I used :set background=dark but that didn't help so it's apparently some other setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the "brute force" answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952424/how-do-you-reset-defaults-for-vi

```
:set all&
```